# Responsive drop down click/hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I am currently coding my first responsive website (I am a beginner in general) and I stumble across plenty obstacles. One of them is an issue with my menu. I'll try and be as specific as possible. 
I have a horizontal menu for desktop and a vertical for tablet/mobile. I have no idea how to resolve the problem of hover in tab/mob version. I have a little toggle script for animating the drop down but what happens is that it drops down every time I click or hover over. How do I disable hover? I'd like to completely remove hover from my website but I then don't know how to style the drop down. I think I have tried everything. I would also be grateful for helping me out with the script. I will appreciate any help.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar li").click(function(){
  $("li.nav_slide").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
</script>



    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <nav>
    <ul class="navbar"> 
      <li><a href='#'><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe600;" class="icon-home"></a></li> 
      <li><a href="sub/who_we_are.hmtl/">WHO WE ARE</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">WHAT WE DO</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="nav_slide"><a href="sub/club_nights.html/">CLUB NIGHTS</a></li>
          <li class="nav_slide"><a href="sub/festivals.html/">FESTIVALS</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">WHAT WE OFFER</a> 
        <ul>
          <li class="nav_slide"><a href="sub/full_system.html/">FULL SYSTEM</a></li>
          <li class="nav_slide"><a href="sub/individual_eq.html/">INDIVIDUAL EQ</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>
     </nav>
     </div>
     </body>
```

```css
<!--desktop-->
  .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  max-width: 1500px;
  background-image: url('home.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

nav {  
  position: relative;
  top: 430px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 600px;  
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;    
}  

nav ul {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}  

nav li { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;  
  width: 135px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}  

nav li:first-child {
  width: 30px;
}

li.menu_icons {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: right;
}

ul li a{
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover{
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li ul{
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul{
  display: block; /* display the dropdown */
  float: none; 
  background-color: #813C7D;
  width: 135px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:hover li{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #813C7D;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

li:hover li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li:hover li a {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li a {   
  box-sizing:border-box;  
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link { color: white; }
/* visited link */
a:visited { color: white; }
/* selected link */
a:active { color: white; font-weight: bold; }

a:link { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover {text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:active{ text-decoration: none; }
}
}

<!--tab/mob-->


   .container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

nav {  
  position: static;
  width: 100%;  
  background: none; 
  font-size: 15px;   
  height: auto; 
}  

nav ul {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #813C7D;
}  

nav li { 
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav li:first-child {
  display: none;
}

nav li ul:first-child {
  display: block;
}

ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul li a{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_slide {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: you need to provide the code you currently have (ie your 'little toggle script' and the code that 'hooks it in'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add in the post what you have done so far (code), this way we can probably point you at what you need to remove for it to work.

Comment: Sorry, had a little bit of trouble with adding the code. It's done now

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't place code outside the `<html>` tags.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first question, it's fixed now. I do have it right in my html

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the css that have `:Hover`

That would give something like this : (Does it work as intended?)

```css
  .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  max-width: 1500px;
  background-image: url('home.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

nav {  
  position: relative;
  top: 430px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 600px;  
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;    
}  

nav ul {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}  

nav li { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;  
  width: 135px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}  

nav li:first-child {
  width: 30px;
}

li.menu_icons {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: right;
}

ul li a{
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul{
  display: none;
}

nav li a {   
  box-sizing:border-box;  
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link { color: white; }
/* visited link */
a:visited { color: white; }
/* selected link */
a:active { color: white; font-weight: bold; }

a:link { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover {text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:active{ text-decoration: none; }


<!--tab/mob-->


   .container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

nav {  
  position: static;
  width: 100%;  
  background: none; 
  font-size: 15px;   
  height: auto; 
}  

nav ul {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #813C7D;
}  

nav li { 
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav li:first-child {
  display: none;
}

nav li ul:first-child {
  display: block;
}

ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul li a{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_slide {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. The script then doesn't work. I don't think that it would be the script itself, but rather what's blocking it from working is no style for drop down elements

Answer (score 0):

Creating responsive navbars from scratch can be a real hassle.

This isn't exactly answering your question but if you don't want to do the dirty work yourself, my recommendation would be to use eg. Bootstrap's navbar component
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar